# nodejs grunt plugin using async module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, grunt.js

I'm looking for some code review of my usage of async. Mainly why this does not work without the `done = this.async()` method and why I don't have to invoke 'done()' on every request to download a file. This is working now but it is a bit of magic to me. Hoping to understand why it's working and if I'm abusing something.

```
   /*
   * grunt-esri-slurp
   * https://github.com/steveoh/grunt-esri-slurp
   *
   * Copyright (c) 2014 steveoh
   * Licensed under the MIT license.
   */

    'use strict';
    var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),

    async = require('async'),
    mkdirp = require('mkdirp'),
    request = require("request"),
    S = require('string'),

    unwind = require('./unwinder'),
    esriModules = require('./esriModules');

  module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('esri_slurp', 'download esri js api amd modules and create a package', function() {
      var options = this.options({
          packageLocation: 'src/esri/',
          version: '3.9'
        }),
        done = this.async();

      options.packageLocation = S(options.packageLocation).ensureRight('/').s;

      grunt.log.subhead('downloading esri version ' + options.version + ' modules');

      mkdirp.sync(options.packageLocation);

      var esriVersionBaseUrl = 'http://js.arcgis.com/' + options.version + 'amd/js/esri/';
      grunt.verbose.writeln('esri base url: ' + esriVersionBaseUrl);

      async.eachLimit(esriModules, 10, function(file, callback) {
        var subPath = file.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
          fileFolder = options.packageLocation + subPath,
          fileName = path.basename(file),
          httpUrl = esriVersionBaseUrl + subPath + fileName;

        if (!fs.existsSync(fileFolder)) {
          grunt.verbose.writeln(['creating folder ' + fileFolder]);

          mkdirp.sync(fileFolder);
        }

        grunt.verbose.writeln(['requesting ' + httpUrl]);

        request({
            uri: httpUrl,
            encoding: 'binary'
          },
          function(error, response, body) {
            if (body && body.length > 0) {
              grunt.verbose.or.write('.');
              grunt.verbose.writeln(['writing: ' + options.packageLocation + file]);

              var f = S(file);
              if (f.endsWith('.js') || f.endsWith('.css')) {
                body = unwind(body);
              }

              fs.writeFile(options.packageLocation + file, body, 'binary');
            }

            callback(error, body);
          });
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: i'm also working on using the path module to remove platform specific separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.async()` tells grunt that you're doing something async and that it should wait until you call the `done` method. Usually it just goes to the next grunt task when the execution is done. Since you're using the `async` module you can call the `done` method in the third argument to `async.eachLimit` which is supposed to be a function that is called when all the work is done.

```
// tell grunt we're doing something async
var done = this.async();

async.eachLimit(['unicorn', 'rainbows'], 10, function(file, cb) {
    // do something async
    cb(); // tell `async` we're done doing work for this item
}, function (err) { // called when all the items have called their `cb()`
    if (err) {
        grunt.warn(err);
    }

    // all the items are done, let's tell grunt we are done
    done();
});
```

Comment: thanks @Sindre. I will add the third callback to each and done() it in there, but how is it that it works now as is?

Comment: @Steve It shouldn't, as `done` is never called so grunt will just wait forever. Might be that grunt has an async timeout or something. Either way, it's just pure luck if it does work.

Comment: crazy how that works @Sindre. https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-esri-slurp is up and working great! thanks again.